# NSString newbie question about setting a char from it

Tags: c, string, nsstring, char

Ok,  I know this is a very basic question,  but my head is swimming in NSString vs C string
nonsense.

Basically I have a `NSString` the just contain 1 character  for example the letter D

How do I take that 1 character  `NSString` and assign it to a variable of char

So I have...

```
char mychar;
NSString *myMode = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:0]];
//myMode ends up hold the letter D.   How do I get it into mychar??
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`characterAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex:).  However, this returns a Unicode character (`unichar`).  If you know that the character is definitely ASCII, you can safely cast it to a `char`:

```
char theChar = (char)[myString characterAtIndex:0];
```